# basic c programming array of string

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf, character

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*functions
int addHugeNumbers(char *a1,char *a2, char *res);

*/


/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main() {

    /*variables*/
    char str[1001];
    int i;
    /**/

    printf("Give the string that contains the numbers that you want to add.\n");
    printf("The strings must not contain more than 1000 characters.\n");
    scanf(" %s",&str);
    for(i=0;i<1001;i++){
        printf("element is %s",str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}'
```

Comment: sorry for the wrong post i am new i have this code and i want to print every one char of this string

Comment: i cant find where i am wrong

Comment: `scanf("%1000s", str);printf("element is ");
    for(i=0; str[i];i++){
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }`

Comment: When you compile, always use `-Wall`, and always fix every warning that you get.

Comment: What is your question? What is the output? What should be?

Comment: Also this `scanf(" %s",&str);` should really be `..., str);` as `str` decays to the address of its first element.

Comment: @alk and maybe `("%1000s"...)` also, right? :)

Comment: This looks like homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, let me tell you, there is no *array of string* in your code, it's an array of `char`s.

Coming to the problem, it is twofold.

Firstly, to print a `char`, you need to use `%c` format specifier, `%s` is for *strings* (null-terminated `char` arrays).

Secondly, in your looping condition. When you say

```
for(i=0;i<1001;i++)
```

the index iterates over **all** the elements of the array. However, if your input is less than 1000 `char`s, then, some part of the array remains uninitialized. Accessing uninitialized variable value invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Basically, instead of looping over the *whole* array, you should do something like

```
 int len = strlen(str);
 for(i=0; i<len; i++)
      printf("element is %c",str[i]);
```

which will limit your index to *valid* values.

That said, the `scanf()` statement should better be like

```
scanf("%1000s",str);   //protect from buffer overflow from reallylonginputstring.....
```

Comment: oooooooooo hhhh thank you very much i am really excited

Comment: this site is the best it can really help people to understand programming languages thanks

Answer (score 2):

Characters are printed using `%c`, the `%s` format specifier expects a 0-terminated string.

You should also not iterate past `strlen(str)` since maybe all input won't be a full 1000 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Right now your `for` loop condition may be causing you to iterate over undefined elements in your `char` array (string).

You'll want to change your `for` loop condition to something like

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

where `length` is defined as `int length = strlen(str);` which would be the length of the string up to, but not including the null terminator.

Sounds like your pretty new to C programming. I'd recommend reading a bit about [Strings in C](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson9.html) and [Buffer Overflows](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/buffer-overflow/) since they're topics worth knowing and being careful about.

Edit: as mentioned in the other answers, you should use `%c` to print out each character, not `%s`.